# How can I make Angular provide GrandChildComponent with the same Service instance of ParentComponent and ChildComponent?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to provide GrandchildComponent with the same Service instance of ChildComponent.
ChildComponent could receive the Service from his parent component or have his own Service instance if his parent didn't provide him with one.

I've tried providing my Service both in ParentComponent and in ChildComponent. To ChildComponent I've added `@SkipSelf()` to make it receive the same instance of ParentComponent. The problem is that GrandChildComponent receives another instance of the Service. This is happening even though the Service is not provided in root and not in GrandchildComponent.

How can I get GrandchildComponent to receive the same instance ParentComponent and ChildComponent have?

[Example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-host-decorator-example-1-wb5udt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this happens, because you are providing a new Service in the Child-Component. The Child-Component then uses the parent service (because of SkipSelf) und the Grand-Child-Compomonent uses the Service provided by the Child Component.

Try using this to conditionally create and provide a Service if the parent does not provide one

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RandomService,
      useFactory: (parentInjector: Injector, randomService?: RandomService) => {
        if (!randomService) {
          const injector = Injector.create({
            providers: [{ provide: RandomService }],
            parent: parentInjector,
          });
          randomService = injector.get(RandomService);
        }

        return randomService;
      },
      deps: [Injector, [new Optional(), new SkipSelf(), RandomService]],
    },
  ],
```